# Maui - Connect To Mac fails with dotnet sdk installation failed

Tags: maui

With the latest VS for windows installed (17.7.5) and dotnet 7.0.402 sdk installed on windows and the mac (had the problem since .net 7), when i try "connect to mac",it fails to detect the Mac already has the SDK installed even though it can be seen via dotnet --info, then attempts to install it and fails to access the azureedge url:

The verbose logs dont really add much:
dotnet-install: Calling: machine_has curl
dotnet-install: Calling: downloadcurl https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/7.0.402-servicing.23480.29/dotnet-sdk-7.0.402-servicing.23480.29-osx-arm64.tar.gz /var/folders/fl/0f7vh_xj6bv_cfh79mpw__hc0000gn/T//dotnet.ESdQ7Nagb
curl: (7) Failed to connect to dotnetcli.azureedge.net port 443 after 3 ms: Couldn't connect to server
dotnet-install: Unable to download https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/7.0.402-servicing.23480.29/dotnet-sdk-7.0.402-servicing.23480.29-osx-arm64.tar.gz. Failed to reach the server: connection timeout.
./dotnet-install.sh: line 1024: http_code: unbound variable

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as Microsoft triaged it back in August.
Everything worked with Maui v6.

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Ive made some progress.......there was some old anti virus software blocking the connection so i can now run the install command manually on the mac and it installs the dotnet framework without any errors. However, VS for windows is still not seeing the sdk and is trying to download and reinstall it every time - as though the SDK needs more setup despite appearing in dotnet --info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Microsoft:

The dotnet Maui connect to Mac process has changed from the xamarin process.
Previously you install the SDK and the build process uses the global sdk

With the dotnet Maui connect to Mac, it looks for a user specific SDK ignoring any globally installed SDKs. When not found, it does a user specific install, leaving the global sdks untouched.

In my case, my Mac does not have internet access when connected to the work network so it cannot install and unlike with Xamarin i cannot install it manually.

Comment: You have worked the issue out. So you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) for other people to refer to.